# Parse XML from a stream on Windows 8.1 store app

Tags: c#, xml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to write my first windows 8.1 / windows phone 8.1 store app and I'm trying to find a simple way to parse XML that comes from a Zip file.

I have a very large zip file (100MB+) that contains lots of small files and I'm trying to read one XML file from it and parse it.

I'm using the `ZipArchive` and `ZipArchiveEntry` classes from `System.IO.Compression` to get a stream to the individual file without needing to decompress the whole zip file but `System.Xml.XmlDocument` class doesn't appear to be available on store apps so the only way I can find to parse this stream is `System.Xml.XmlReader` but I want to use XPath, and other DOM methods to access the XML contents.

WinRT seems to have `Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument` instead but this doesn't seem to accept a stream, only `IStorageFile`.

Is there a simple, clean and efficient way of getting this single XML file out of the zip archive and parsing it without having to store it in a temporary file and read it back in?

Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: If the file is small couldn't you just read it into a string and construct your document from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [System.Xml.XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx) from your stream and load it into a [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356384(v=vs.110).aspx) for parsing. Both of these are available to Windows Store apps.

If you need Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument's functionality you can either load it from a string or convert your stream to a StorageFile with [StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.createstreamedfileasync.aspx) without round tripping through a temp file.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take advantage of Windows Runtime Interop extension methods [storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.windowsruntimestorageextensions_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) and [streams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.windowsruntimestreamextensions(v=vs.110).aspx). Just reference the namespace and it will allow you to obtain .net streams or convert existing streams to .net streams. Simple example :

```
// using statement

using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;

// then in your class

private async Task<XDocument> OpenXmlFile() {
    var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///XmlFile1.xml"));
    XDocument doc;
    using (var fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync()) {
      doc = XDocument.Load(fileStream);
    }
    return doc;
}
```